# Retrofit response null

Tags: android, retrofit

I try to call this Request with Retrofit

[image]

my code :

```
 Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();


Clientn client = new Clientn();
final WaselJsonPlaceHolderApi apiService = client.getClient().create(WaselJsonPlaceHolderApi.class);

Call<TokenModel> call = apiService.getLoginToken( "password", "ec_user","EC_P@ssw0rd" , "0500344253", "1993");

call.enqueue(new Callback<TokenModel>() {
     @Override
     public void onResponse(Call<TokenModel> call, Response<TokenModel> response) {
          Log.e("TAG-TAG", ""+response.errorBody());
          Log.e("TAG-TAG", ""+response.body());

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<TokenModel> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

the **Interface** :

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api/CustomerAccount/LoginUserByMobile")
Call<TokenModel> getLoginToken( @Field("grant_type") String title,
                                @Field("app_username") String body,
                                @Field("app_password") String password,
                                @Field("mobile_number") String userId, 
                                @Field("ver_code") String code );
```

the **Client**

```
    public class Clientn {

        public static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.1.230/MagicWord.ECommercPlatform.API/";
        public static Retrofit retrofit = null;

        public static Retrofit getClient(){
            if (retrofit == null){
                retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
            }
            return retrofit;
        }

    }
```

but i get the null response and the ErrorBody is `E/TAG-TAG: okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@aa2472e`

Comment: try hit url with postman and check if you are getting response or not.?

Comment: Please provide a Mock Server by postman to make available your api. It helps us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think android stopped response for normal **http** in latest API(29), You can try with **https** and check the same issue is coming or not.

Answer (score 0):

i think the issue is in your "ver_code which is int or use are taking string.is it string or int?

Comment: the ver_code request is string and i pass it as string

Answer (score 0):

`onFailure` callback could be very useful, try to add `t.printStacktrace()` on it.

Also, don't pass an object as is with a string on Log, because it will just print an address that you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

Keep field name and variable name same

Example:

```
@Field("grant_type") String grant_type,  @Field("app_username") String app_username,@Field("app_password") app_password
```

so that you cannot get confused.

I think the request method should be **POST**
Because in code the request method is **POST** but in screenshot the request method is **GET**